# In Angular, why RouterEvent object is different for loading page through user click Navigation and through Refresh

Tags: angular, typescript

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
        console.log('event-------', JSON.stringify(event))
})
```

Below are the event object if observe on `router.events`, using above code:

If page loads through navigation i.e. through click event:

```
{"id":2,"url":"/abc.xyz","type":0,"navigationTrigger":"imperative","restoredState":null}
```

If page loads through page refresh:

```
{"routerEvent":{"id":1,"url":"/abc.xyz","urlAfterRedirects":"/abc.xyz","type":1},"position":null,"anchor":null,"type":15}
```

How to make sure event object should be consistent on user click event and page refresh.
Pls help.

Comment: if you read the manual, you can see that the events are a plethora of different types: https://angular.io/api/router/Event and you can distinguish them by EventType https://angular.io/api/router/EventType .
also: no need to `stringify` stuff into console.log, just give it your objects for a better debugging experience

Answer (score 0):

You can just apply a ternary condition since either the expected object appears at the root level or inside the `routerEvent` property.

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    const data = event && event.routerEvent ? event.routerEvent : event;
    console.log('event-------', JSON.stringify(data))
});
```

As to why the data looks so different, please provide a stackblitz with the issue replicated for checking this issue.